# Render React into Shadow Root

Tags: reactjs, shadow-dom

I am trying to encapsulate **React Component in Shadow Root**. The component is rendered without a problem, but ***events are not working***. My code looks like this:

```
let shadow = document.getElementById('root').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadow.innerHTML = "<div id='panel'></div>";


ReactDOM.render(
    <Admin />,
    shadow.getElementById('panel')
);
```

The version of React is 15.4.2.
I went through the list of issues and can't understand if this is a React issue or I am doing something wrong.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known react issue.

There are number of discussions ([here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/event-handling-with-the-shadow-dom-and-react/14580), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1877), [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5052), and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1167)) that refer to this issue, below is an excerpt from one of them:

> The problem is that React has a global event handler on the document
>   and the shadow DOM retargets the event to make it look like it came
>   from the host node. This prevents React from passing the event to the
>   right element.

Comment: Might be useful to at least summarise the content of those links.  If those links go dead, this answer becomes _a lot_ less useful

Comment: Completely agree - will do that as soon as I will get to my PC.

Comment: @Amid thanks for the links! So there is no way to use shadow root with react? is that right?

Comment: Not any 'canonical' way, as one of the links shows facebook has no plans on implementing it either. There are projects like https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow but I have no experience using them.

Comment: Events will work if you render your React app directly into shadow root, not some child node in it.